# php variable[1] meaning in actual coding

Tags: php

Question about php `$variable[1]`

What does it mean ?

```
$variable[1] 
$variable[2]
```

I saw in some codes it array , what does it actually mean and present

Comment: Learn https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: If `$variable` is an array, it gets or sets the value of the index with either 1 or 2. Can be used on strings as well, to pluck the letters of that position. Keep in mind, PHP is zero-indexed (starts at 0, not 1).

Comment: in case variable is string or array, will give you this:- https://3v4l.org/O58h7   Or may be this:- https://3v4l.org/cm8FG

Answer (score 1):

it means that `$variable` is an array and you are calling the index (1/2).

Comment: It does not automatically mean its an array. It can be used on strings, too!

Comment: a string is an array of chars

Comment: Uhh, no, it isn't.. It's a combination of multiple characters, but it's not an array. That's a different type.

Comment: its not just an array of chars but it has one and it gives direct acces to it
[see this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details)

Comment: A string and an array are two very different things. But, *in PHP*, you can access the specific characters of a string with using `$string[2]`, the same way you can access elements in an array. That does not make a string an array, they are still two different types.